# SQLDF merge in R: counting NA values between two dates

Tags: r, merge, na, sqldf

I am trying to merge two datasets using SQLDF in R. I am calculating an average value for dat1 of the values that fall between two dates in dat2. I want to count the number of NA values that are between these two dates in dat2.

```
dat3= sqldf("select a.ID, avg(b.mean_pm25) as avg_pm
                from dat1 a
                left join dat2 b
                on a.ZIP=b.ZIP and (b.pm_date between a.startdate and a.enddate)
               group by a.ID")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a conditional aggregation to query. Two versions are shown below with and without `CASE` statement.

```sql
select d1.ID
       , avg(d2.mean_pm25) as avg_pm
       , sum(d2.mean_pm25 IS NULL) as count_pm_nas
       , sum(case 
                  when d2.mean_pm25 IS NULL
                  then 1
                  else 0
             end) as count_pm_nas_alternative
from dat1 d1
left join dat2 d2
     on d1.ZIP = d2.ZIP 
    and (d2.pm_date between d1.startdate and d1.enddate)
group by d1.ID
```

Also, for best practice in SQL querying, consider [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in data frame `BOD` add some NAs to provide test data and then count them:

```
library(sqldf)
BOD$Time[3:4] <- NA  # test data

sqldf("select sum(Time is null) as no_of_na from BOD")
##   no_of_na
## 1        2
```